# Flutter input formatting in textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart, text-formatting

I'm trying to format textformfield while typing. I've managed to get it working...well sort of. Currently the textformfield takes in number and works like this:

user types in number for example "1" - > user types in second number ex. "2" the formatting changes the value to "1.2" by adding . in between -> user types in a third number "3" the formatting changes the value to "12.3".

Now my issue is that this is a price field and I want to round up to two digits after the . SO it would be 1.00, 1.20 or 12.30.

I've been sitting on this for a bit now and I have no idea how to make it work.

I want to make sure that there cannot be more than 5 characters inside with largest value example (12.30)

The Code:

```
TextFormField(
                  validator: (fuelPriceValue) {
                    if (fuelPriceValue!.isEmpty) {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  onChanged: (fuelPriceValue) {
                    fuelPrice = (fuelPriceValue as TextEditingController);
                  },
                  controller: fuelPrice,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'\d*')),
                    TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3);
                      if (newValue.text.length == 2) {
                        return TextEditingValue(
                            text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 1)}.${newValue.text.substring(1)}',
                            selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length + 1))
                        );
                      }
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4);
                      if (newValue.text.length == 3) {
                        return TextEditingValue(
                            text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 2)}.${newValue.text.substring(2)}',
                            selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length + 1))
                        );
                      }
                      if (newValue.text.length == 4) {
                        return TextEditingValue(
                            text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 2)}.${newValue.text.substring(2)}',
                            selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length))
                        );
                      }
                      return TextEditingValue(
                        text: newValue.text,
                        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newValue.text.length),
                      );
                    }),
                  ],
                  // inputFormatters: [
                  //   LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
                  //   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'\d*')),
                  //   TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
                  //
                  //     LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3);
                  //     if (newValue.text.length == 2) {
                  //       return TextEditingValue(
                  //           text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 1)}.${newValue.text.substring(1)}',
                  //           selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length + 1))
                  //       );
                  //     }
                  //     LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4);
                  //     if (newValue.text.length == 3) {
                  //       return TextEditingValue(
                  //           text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 2)}.${newValue.text.substring(2)}',
                  //           selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length + 1))
                  //       );
                  //     }
                  //     if (newValue.text.length == 4) {
                  //       return TextEditingValue(
                  //           text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 2)}.${newValue.text.substring(2)}',
                  //           selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length))
                  //       );
                  //     }
                  //     return TextEditingValue(
                  //       text: newValue.text,
                  //       selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newValue.text.length),
                  //     );
                  //   }),
                  // ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10))),
```

Comment: why use "TextInput", dropdown instead.

Comment: I wish I could. It has to be text input. Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just idea not final solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TextExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextExample> createState() => _TextExampleState();
}

class _TextExampleState extends State<TextExample> {
  TextEditingController c = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: c,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  //TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: c.text.length));
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9.]")),
                  TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
                  String input = newValue.text;
                  if(input.length==2){
                    if(!input.contains(".")){
                      input = input[0] + "."+input[1];
                    }else{
                    }
                  }
                  if(input.length==3){
                    if(input.contains(".")){
                      input = input.replaceAll(".", "");
                      input = input[0] + "."+input[1];
                    }else{
                    }
                  }
                  if(input.length==4){
                    var count = '.'.allMatches(input).length;
                    if(count>1){
                      input = oldValue.text;
                      return upr(input);
                    }else if(count==1){
                      if(input.contains(".") && input.length==4){
                        // var position = input.indexOf('.');
                        input = input.replaceAll(".", "");
                        input = input[0] + input[1]+"."+input[2];
                        if(int.parse(input[0]) != 1){
                          input = oldValue.text;
                          return upr(input);
                        }
                        if(int.parse(input[0]) == 1 && int.parse(input[1])>2 ){
                          input = oldValue.text;
                          return upr(input);
                        }
                        if(int.parse(input[0]) == 1 && int.parse(input[1])<3 && int.parse(input[3])>3){
                          input = oldValue.text;
                          return upr(input);
                        }
                        if(int.parse(input[0]) != 1 && int.parse(input[1])< 3 ){
                          input = oldValue.text;
                          return upr(input);
                        }
                      }

                    }else{
                      input = oldValue.text;
                      return upr(input);
                    }
                  }
                  if(input.length>4){
                     input = oldValue.text;
                     return upr(input);
                  }
                  return upr(input);
                  }),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
TextEditingValue upr(input){
    TextEditingValue  val1 = TextEditingValue(
      text:input,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: input.length))
      );
    return val1 ;
}
```

Comment: Unforunately that does the same thing my code does.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've managed to answer the question myself. THank you for suggestions.

Here is the updated code:

In my widget class I've added

```
final RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'^\d{2}\.\d{2}$');
```

And here is the inputFormatter from textformfield

```
inputFormatters: [
                      new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),

                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'\d*')),
                      TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
                        if (newValue.text.length == 1 && newValue.text.length > oldValue.text.length) {
                          return TextEditingValue(
                              text: '${newValue.text}.00',
                              selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length + 3))
                          );
                        }
                        if (newValue.text.length == 4) {
                          return TextEditingValue(
                              text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 1)}.${newValue.text.substring(3)}0',
                              selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length + 1))
                          );
                        }
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5);
                        if (newValue.text.length == 5) {
                            if (!regExp.hasMatch(oldValue.text)) {
                              return TextEditingValue(
                                  text: '${newValue.text.substring(0, 1)}${newValue.text.substring(
                                      3, 4)}.${newValue.text.substring(4)}0',
                                  selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
                                      TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length))
                              );
                            } else {
                              return  TextEditingValue(
                                  text: oldValue.text,
                                  selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
                                      TextPosition(offset: newValue.text.length))
                              );
                            }
                        }
                        return TextEditingValue(
                          text: newValue.text,
                          selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newValue.text.length),
                        );
                      }),
                    ],
```